# Using page properties as web part properties

Tags: content-query-web-part, column

Specifically in the content query web part, can I filter by a column whose value is passed in based on a particular page property (the pages have some custom columns to aid in SEO and indexing, one of which is a unique tracking code), in the same vein as say, [Me] ?

The purpose of this exercise is that I am creating a "template" page that we copy and change, but I don't want to have to edit the page each time to change the three content-query web parts to all have the same value for this column, when it is always in the page properties.

Comment: Are you using enterprise?

Comment: Hi. Page properties are just list item properties, since a page is jsut a list item. It shouldn't be too difficult, but you'd have to delve a bit into the XSLT to get it going. Sorry, but i dont have any examples, thus not adding as a answer.

Comment: @Lori, yes it is enterprise for 07

Answer (score 1):

Are you working with sharepoint 2007 or 2010? When working with SharePoint 2010, you are very, very lucky. Microsoft introduced to use pagefield values in your content by query webpart! You can read more about it on MSDN: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ecm/archive/2010/05/14/what-s-new-with-the-content-query-web-part.aspx It allows you to create context driven webparts, isn't that cool? ;)

And as a bonus: include your content by query webpart in your page layout, you will just one place to manage your webpart, which will save you a lot of time when changing the query ;).

Comment: Oh man, this would be perfect!  Unfortunately we are on 07.  Is there any way to do this on the 07 platform?